# Showing continuity of specific functions (relations involved)

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let  $f : X \to Y$ be continuous.
Let $R$ be equivalence relation on $X$ such that $xRy$ only if $f(x) = f(y)$
and $S$ be equivalence relation on $Y$.

Let $g: X/R \to Y$ where $g([x]_R) := f(x)$ and
$h: X \to Y/S$ where $h(x) := [f(x)]_S$.

Are functions $g$ and $h$ continuous? I must admit I don't have an idea how to approach such problem. Any insights are welcome, thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

$g$ is continuous as $g \circ q_R = f$ and $f$ is continuous, by the universal property of quotients.

$h$ is just the composition $q_S \circ f$ so continuous as a composition of continuous maps. Note that $f$ does not have any relation to $S$, so $h$ is less likely to be a useful map.